# What species are these baby birds?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

I'm trying to save these baby birds' lives, and I need to know their species so that I can know how/what to feed them. Please help me ASAP .

[image]
[image]

Comment: A couple of questions; where did you find them, in what condition? [allaboutbirds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/browse/topic/faqs/) advises to contact licensed wildlife rehab centre or leave them to the place where they were found to increase their chances of survival. The bird appears to be one from [Caprimulgiformes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caprimulgiformes).

Comment: I agree they look like Caprimulgiformes. We need more info (where you live, where you found them, why you are holding them, etc.) to answer your question. Also, in the future, if you find baby birds, just leave them where you found them. These look fully fledged, and were almost certainly ok and just waiting for mom to come back to feed them...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are in Europe they are [juvenile common swift](http://www.wildlives.org.uk/news_letters-2/2012/October/pics/1.htm) (*Apus apus*).

There is a website dedicated to them, with a page on how to raise them: http://www.commonswift.org/Hand_rearing_Swifts.html

They are very fragile and with the wrong diet they might develop feather deformations. They also require a continuous effort because they eat very often. I raised them a couple of times and when they take off is magnificent but it is easy to do something wrong. If you have some recovery center or expert nearby  I suggest to hand them over.

Comment: +1 For the website you linked. I mistook them for nightjars.